# ng-show in ng-repeated list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I need the .overlay div to show when an item on the list is selected. ng-show works on a 'p' or similar, but it doesn't with this current display? Any help really appreciated!
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nick_1002/zvhqvzjt/4/)

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" class="app">
        <ul>
            <input type="text" ng-model="queryStyle" />
            <li ng-repeat="style in style | filter:queryStyle" ng-class="{active:( $parent.selectedStyle == $index)}" ng-click="$parent.selectedStyle = $index;$parent.style.doClick(style);show == !show">
                <h1>{{style.id}}</h1></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="overlay" ng-show="show">
            <h2>{{styleTags}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Contoller: -

```
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.style = [{
        id: "1",
        style: "one"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        style: "Two"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        style: "Three"
    }];
    $scope.style.doClick = function(style) {
        $scope.styleTags = style.style;
    }
    $scope.toggle = function(item) {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
    };
    $scope.filterFunction = function(element) {
        return element.name.match(/^Ma/) ? true : false;
    };

});
CSS:
    .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin - left: auto;
        margin - right: auto;
        height: 100 % ;
        width: 100 % ;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85)
    }
    .active {
        background - color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had mistakes which were removed. There were few thing I changed.

1. This `show == !show` was not an assignment, it was `show =!show` for
   toggle.
2. You do not need to write expressions on `ng-click` instead make a
   function and do the coding there.
3. You don't need `$parent` to access the local functions

Here is the [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/nmtb44z7/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="app">
    <ul>
      <input type="text" ng-model="queryStyle" />
      <li ng-repeat="style in style | filter:queryStyle" 
        ng-class="{active:( selectedStyle == $index)}" 
        ng-click="doClick(style, $index);">
        <h1>{{style.id}}</h1></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="overlay" ng-show="showOverlay">
      <h2>{{styleTags}}</h2>
    </div>
```

```
        $scope.showOverlay = false;
        $scope.myData = {};
        $scope.style = [{
            id: "1",
            style: "one"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            style: "Two"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            style: "Three"
        }];
        $scope.doClick = function (style, index) {
            $scope.selectedStyle = index;
            $scope.styleTags = style.style;
            $scope.showOverlay = true;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Makes a lot more sense now. Still trying to get my head around angular... slowly.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this my taking the output of the filtered styles into a variable and show hide your overlay div based on that.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="app">
      <ul>
        <input type="text" ng-model="queryStyle" />
        <li ng-repeat="style in styles | filter:queryStyle as filteredStyles"><h1>{{style.id}}</h1></li>
    </ul>    
    <div class="overlay" ng-show="filteredStyles.length > 0 && styles.length > filteredStyles.length">
    <h2>Selected Style is {{filteredStyles[0].style}}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Check the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zvhqvzjt/8/

i have changed your style array to styles and removed some unnecessary code of doclick and toggle.

I also removed the overlay class css since it was making the whole screen read only, you can add it again if required.